# Remove one of the OSes from the SD card

Tags: raspbian, noobs, partition

I've installed both Raspbian and OSMC using NOOBs into 1 sd card.

Is there a way to remove OSMC to free up some space? I have Kodi inside raspbian so OSMC is kind of redundant.

My SD is 16gb.

Thank you!

Comment: This may help https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58811